# How can I list docker container names along with node version

Tags: node.js, linux, docker, command-line

I was wondering if there is a smart way to output all docker names along with the version of node.js they are running for the containse/service.

I can run;

```
docker ps --format '{{.Names}}'
```

...to get a list of all names, but then I'm stuck running;

```
docker exec <NAME goes HERE> node -v
```

...for each item NAME one-by-one to find out the NODE.JS version linked to it (which is somewhat tedious and time consuming even with my fast fingers and copy/paste tool)

Is there a way of combining these two commands into one to output name and node version? Or are we into a linux-scripting-type territory here?!

Please note; I've found these commands via googling and only really understand the docker basics like stop/start/listing stuff out...

Many thanks in advance for any information or answers received!

Comment: Maybe this can help you: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/node_ls/

Comment: At the Docker level, it can't tell you anything about the software inside a container or image; that `docker exec` command is about the best you can do, and that does mean you need to write some sort of script.

Comment: @Konflex - i believe the commands here will return the Docker version being run, not the Node.JS version inside those so not quite what I'm looking for - but thank you all the same!

Answer (score 0):

A think a simple bash script should be easy enough.  I don't have docker installed, but you can probably tweak the approach below?

Create script.sh and grant it execute permissions.

from the terminal

```
nano script.sh #paste in script below"

for container in `docker ps -q`; do 
  # show the name of the container
  docker inspect --format='{{.Name}}' $container;
  # run the command
  docker exec {{.Name}} node -v
done
```

make the script executable

```
chmod u+x script.sh
```

Run the script

```
./script.sh
```

Should see the node version printed to tty

Comment: There is no particular reason to save the script in a file; you can simply paste it on the command line if you prefer.

Comment: Also, try http://shellcheck.net/ to have a few stylistic problems pointed out to you, with suggested fixes.

Comment: The OP already figured out how to get a listing of names; I don't see why you go back trough `ps -q` to get their IDs.